# Using curl as an alternative to fopen file resource for fgetcsv

Tags: php, curl, fopen, fgetcsv

Is it possible to make curl, access a url and the result as a file resource? like how fopen does it.

My goals:

1. Parse a CSV file
2. Pass it to fgetcsv

My obstruction: fopen is disabled

My chunk of codes (in fopen)

```
$url = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=USDEUR=X&f=sl1d1t1n&e=.csv";
$f = fopen($url, 'r');
print_r(fgetcsv($f));
```

Then, I am trying this on curl.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$content = @curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

But, as usual. $content already returns a string.

Now, is it possible for curl to return it as a file resource pointer? just like fopen? Using PHP < 5.1.x something. I mean, not using str_getcsv, since it's only 5.3.

My error

> Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at adding the str_getcsv from the comment with the function docs?  http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#100579

Comment: It's only available on 5.3. :(

Comment: And my usual error, because it does not exist yet. Fatal error: Call to undefined function str_getcsv()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that by `fopen is disabled` you mean "`allow_url_fopen` is disabled", a combination of `CURLOPT_FILE` and [`php://temp`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) make this fairly easy:

```
$f = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $f);
// Do you need these? Your fopen() method isn't a post request
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

rewind($f);

while ($line = fgetcsv($f)) {
  print_r($line);
}

fclose($f);
```

Basically this creates a pointer to a "virtual" file, and cURL stores the response in it. Then you just reset the pointer to the beginning and it can be treated as if you had opened it as usual with `fopen($url, 'r');`

Comment: I tried to get the resource type by issuing.. get_resource_type($f); It returns a "stream", is this correct? Same error, Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: Solved it. This is definitely the answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried in PHP 5.5.6 local xampp, the ***print_r($line);*** does not output anything, is there any other settings needed?

Comment: I found the problem, it is due to my target is using HTTPS which I need to turn off SSL verification. It is ok now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary file using `fopen()` and then `fwrite()` the contents into it. After that, the newly created file will be readable by `fgetcsv()`. The [`tempnam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) function should handle the creation of arbitrary temporary files.

According to the comments on [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php), users without access to the command could try the function below. There are also various other approaches in the comments, make sure you check them out.

```
function str_getcsv($input, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"', $escape = '\\', $eol = '\n') {
    if (is_string($input) && !empty($input)) {
        $output = array();
        $tmp    = preg_split("/".$eol."/",$input);
        if (is_array($tmp) && !empty($tmp)) {
            while (list($line_num, $line) = each($tmp)) {
                if (preg_match("/".$escape.$enclosure."/",$line)) {
                    while ($strlen = strlen($line)) {
                        $pos_delimiter       = strpos($line,$delimiter);
                        $pos_enclosure_start = strpos($line,$enclosure);
                        if (
                            is_int($pos_delimiter) && is_int($pos_enclosure_start)
                            && ($pos_enclosure_start < $pos_delimiter)
                            ) {
                            $enclosed_str = substr($line,1);
                            $pos_enclosure_end = strpos($enclosed_str,$enclosure);
                            $enclosed_str = substr($enclosed_str,0,$pos_enclosure_end);
                            $output[$line_num][] = $enclosed_str;
                            $offset = $pos_enclosure_end+3;
                        } else {
                            if (empty($pos_delimiter) && empty($pos_enclosure_start)) {
                                $output[$line_num][] = substr($line,0);
                                $offset = strlen($line);
                            } else {
                                $output[$line_num][] = substr($line,0,$pos_delimiter);
                                $offset = (
                                            !empty($pos_enclosure_start)
                                            && ($pos_enclosure_start < $pos_delimiter)
                                            )
                                            ?$pos_enclosure_start
                                            :$pos_delimiter+1;
                            }
                        }
                        $line = substr($line,$offset);
                    }
                } else {
                    $line = preg_split("/".$delimiter."/",$line);

                    /*
                     * Validating against pesky extra line breaks creating false rows.
                     */
                    if (is_array($line) && !empty($line[0])) {
                        $output[$line_num] = $line;
                    } 
                }
            }
            return $output;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: As I have said, fopen is disabled.

Comment: If `fopen()` is completely disabled and you lack `str_getcsv()` (which could be your saviour) then try the approaches described in the comments. Also, see my edit.