# How to convert curl to fopen stream

Tags: php, symfony, google-api, silex, php-curl

I am working with a custom Silex (Symphony) CMS.

One of the custom modules uses `google/apiclient` (https://packagist.org/packages/google/apiclient) module for fetching YouTube video channels and video informations.

On our local environment, for some reason, the ampersand `(&)` of a YouTube request URL gets encoded to `&amp;`, and for this reason it is not working, throwing `failed to open stream: Connection refused` error, while if I open a new browser tab, and paste the URL, and change the `&amp;` into `&`, it works just fine. Tried to use a USA vpn, but no change.

It could be some PHP setting that I am not aware of. Tried to override manually the fetching URL, but the encode happens insde fopen I guess.

So I tried to use `curl` instead of `fopen` to read the URL, inside google/apiclient's Stream.php file, and it reads the URL just fine, it is not throwing any errors. Before that, also tried `file_get_contents()`, same result as with fopen.

Is there a way to transform a `curl` result to an `fopen stream`, to replace only that part of the code, in order to make it work?

Or someone does have another solution for this?

*Note:* `composer update google/apiclient` says "Nothing to update", so either the version was locked down, or it is at the latest version.

Comment: the `&amp;` thing have nothing to do with php settings, your url is simply not properly html_entity_decode()'ed somewhere. and don't convert `&amp;` back to `&`, just run it through html_entity_decode() instead. because guess what, it's not just `&`, you also have problems with `<` which has become `&lt;`, and `>` which has become `&gt;`, and lots of other edge cases like it.

Comment: @hanshenrik, thank you for the feedback, that's definitely true and something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, so I'll leave here for anybody else.

Like I mentioned, in the file `google/apiclient/src/Google/IO/Stream.php`, around line 129, commented out the `set_error_handler` part together with the `fopen`. First I needed to read the content of the URL with curl, using code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867870/using-curl-as-an-alternative-to-fopen-file-resource-for-fgetcsv)

```
$fh = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
rewind($fh);
```

then needed to get the header from the same, which I found how to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/can-php-curl-retrieve-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request)

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($curl);

$header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$http_response_header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);

curl_close($curl);
```

and those did the trick. Hope it is useful to others as well.